# How do I use cluster name with "/" in Cloudera Restful API

Tags: api, cloudera

`/api/v1/clusters` gives me:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "SANDBOX/CI",
    "version" : "CDH5"
  } ]
}
```

To find out all the services on this cluster, the right API is:
`/api/v1/clusters/SANDBOX/CI`

This is NOT working due to the forward slash part of the cluster's name.

Any work around?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a URL-encoded slash (`%2F`) in the name instead of a literal slash?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I changed the api version from v1 to v11, the result is different, the "name" does not have a "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if I go to use API v11 the result is different:
API v1:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "SANDBOX/CI",
    "version" : "CDH5"
  } ]
}
```

API v6 and up:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "cluster",
    "displayName" : "SANDBOX/CI",
    "version" : "CDH5",
    "fullVersion" : "5.12.0",
    "maintenanceMode" : true,
    "maintenanceOwners" : [ "CLUSTER" ]
  } ]
}
```

As you can see the name's value no longer has "/" and I am able to use the API to find out some details on this cluster with the name of "cluster"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

You must use `/api/v1/clusters/SANDBOX%2FCI` in the `curl`.